# create a html form with 2 action pags

Tags: action, forms, http-post

How can i create a html form that action attribute have 2 destination.I want when user click on submit bottom , check if user entered wrong data the page goes to another pages with **window.location** and if user insert the correct input goes to main page with the same instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what do you mean by correct input?
Main form data validation occurs in server side, not client side. you'd better use client side just for simple verification, like for typos.

There is no need for 2 destination pages (as you call it so).
You may use the standard action attribute which is the page on the server to which you are sending your form data.

there, You have the option to decide which condition needs what action and send the data (and then the user) to the desired page / action.

Comment: thank you very much...actually after  i asking this question i find a way that do not need to 2 action pages...

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for the form

```
<form id='myform' action='action.php' method='POST' target='formresponse'>
<label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" /><br/>
<label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br/>
<input type='button' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</form>

<iframe name='formresponse' width='300' height='200'></frame>
```

Multiple action

```
function SubmitForm()
{
     document.forms['contactus'].action='action1.php';
     document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result1';
     document.forms['contactus'].submit();

     document.forms['contactus'].action='action2.php';
     document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result2';
     document.forms['contactus'].submit();
     return true;
}
```

Comment: can target attribute get this value??i see this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp and in that target doesnt have this value?are you sure?